# Как сделать резервное копирование веб-приложения и базы данных на локалке (windows)

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! Есть веб приложение которое работает на локальном компе с ОС Windows. Как с помощью PHP написать скрипт, который делал бы бэкап сайта и бд с дальнейшим сохранением в файлы? Бэкап должен будет автоматически происходить при посещении главной страницы сайта. Конечно, есть программы делающие это, но я бы хотел сделать это сам при помощи PHP если возможно такое.

Comment: вопрос в том, куда будут сохраняться потом файлы? если на тот же диск, то теряется весь смысл бэкапа. может проще все же скопировать файлы вручную на сменный носитель? или использовать git-репозиторий?

Comment: Думаю в папку Гугл диска. А оттуда уже будет идти синхронизация. Копировать файлы не хочется каждый раз. А ещё лучше было бы чтобы все это сжималось

Comment: а почему при посещении страницы, а не скажем по расписанию в плаировщике?

Comment: Если так можно то было бы круто.

Answer (score 1):

Шаг 1 - архивация директории. Под винду с помощью 7zip из командной строки

```
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -r archive_name dir_to_store
```

Конечно, можно использовать любой другой архиватор.

Шаг 2 архивация БД. Например Mysql архивируется так

```
 mysqldump -uroot -h82.82.82.82 -p12345 database_name > database_name.sql
```

Шаг 3 объединить шаги 1 и 2 с помощью PHP. Используем exec(), system() и что вам больше нравится.

```
<?php

chdir('archive_dir');

exec('"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -r archive_name dir_to_store');
exec('mysqldump -uroot -h82.82.82.82 -p12345 database_name > database_name.sql');
```

Не уверен, что все сразу запуститься, но принцип работы именно такой.

Comment: файлы архивируются, а вот файл базы - пустой.

Comment: Пробуйте команду `mysqldump -uroot -h82.82.82.82 -p12345 database_name > database_name.sql` запустить из командной строки. Смотрите на ошибки.

Comment: ошибок нет, файл бд не пустой, когда пробую из командной строки XAMPP. А при обновлении страницы создается пустой файл

Comment: Не стоит делать дампы по обновлению страницы - это долго, скрипты могут "не успеть". Обычно это делается по крону. Возможно exec('mysqldump  ... ') не находит по пути mysqldump. Укажите полный путь до mysqldump.

Comment: Проблема исчезла после того как я добавил путь к mysqldump в переменную среды компьютера. крона, на сколько я знаю нет в XAMРР, поэтому я выбрал такой вариант